# When I multiply my shader with my glm perspective everything just disappears

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, glm-math

I have been trying different parameters just to see if that might be the issue but I still get nothing. I don't know much about this matrix in particular but every way I try to multiply I get the same result which is a black screen. The code I am including below is just a snippet that I think is all that is necessary to see in order to have an idea of what the problem is. Keep in mind that without multiplying my projection matrix by my vertex shader everything works fine.

Here is my perspective and orthographic projection's

```cpp
glm::mat4 theprojectionMatrix = glm::perspective(45.0f, 800.0f/800.0f, 0.1f, 150.0f);

glm::mat4 theOrthographicprojection = glm::ortho(-2.0f, 2.0f, -1.5f, 1.5f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
```

Here are the coordinates of my object. Just including if necessary

```
float vertices[] = { -0.1, -0.1, 2.0,
                      0.1, -0.1, 2.0,
                      0.1, 0.1, 2.0, 
                     -0.1, 0.1, 2.0 };



float vertices2[] = { -0.1,0.1, 2.0,
                      0.1, 0.1, 2.0,
                      0.1, 0.3, 2.0,
                     -0.1, 0.3, 2.0 };


float vertices3[] = {  0.1, 0.1, 2.2,
                       0.1, 0.1, 2.0,
                       0.1, 0.3, 2.0,
                       0.1, 0.3, 2.2 };


float vertices4[] = {  -0.1, 0.1, 2.2,
                       -0.1, 0.1, 2.0,
                       -0.1, 0.3, 2.0,
                       -0.1, 0.3, 2.2 };

unsigned int indices[] = {

0, 1, 2,
2, 3, 0    };
```

Here is the part of my vertex shader you need to see. I am using uniforms

```c
void main()
{
    gl_Position = theOrthographicprojection * theprojectionMatrix * 
        vec4(position.x, position.y, position.z, 1.0);
};
```

Comment: I think you're doing a mad-mix of matrices. Multiplying two projection matrices is not the way. I advise to read a good book/tuto on maths used in 3D geometry.

Comment: @Ripi2 I have tried learning some of the math but i have no foundation. I am in grade 9 that's about the curriculum I know and some multiplying matrices linear algebra stuff I have learned ever since I started using glm.

Comment: @Ripi2 I don't have foundation so I stopped learning the crazy math.

Comment: With this link [Learning Modern 3D Graphics Programming](https://paroj.github.io/gltut/) you can learn maths and OpenGL at once.